# Using hash-union in typed racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm working with hash tables in Typed Racket, and trying to use the (untyped) [`hash-union`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fhash..rkt%29._hash-union%29%29) function from `racket/hash`. Using `require/typed` to import it into my module and call it will pass the type checker and compile.

```lisp
#lang typed/racket/base

(require/typed racket/hash
  [hash-union (All (k v) (->* ((Immutable-HashTable k v))
                              (#:combine (-> v v v) #:combine/key (-> k v v v))
                              #:rest (HashTable k v)
                              (Immutable-HashTable k v)))])

(: pick-first (All (a) (-> a a a)))
(define (pick-first v1 v2) v1)

(: make-ci-table (-> String (Immutable-HashTable Char Integer)))
(define (make-ci-table pat)
  (let ([patlen (string-length pat)])
    ((inst hash-union Char Integer)
     (for/hasheqv : (Immutable-HashTable Char Integer) ([i (in-range patlen)])
       (values (char-upcase (string-ref pat i)) (- patlen 1 i)))
     (for/hasheqv  : (Immutable-HashTable Char Integer) ([i (in-range patlen)])
       (values (char-downcase (string-ref pat i)) (- patlen 1 i)))
     #:combine pick-first)))
```

However, actually running it will cause a contract failure:

```
raco test: (submod "main.rkt" test)
hash/c: contract violation
  expected: chaperone-contract?
  given: k33
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/hash.rkt:61:0: hash/c
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/typed-racket-lib/typed-racket/utils/hash-contract.rkt:28:0: hash/c/check-key
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/typed-racket-lib/typed-racket/utils/hash-contract.rkt:22:0: immutable-hash/c
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/parametric.rkt:26:36
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/parametric.rkt:82:7: wrap
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/parametric.rkt:100:10
   ...
```

The equivalent in normal Racket runs fine. It appears to be failing in testing if a table is immutable if I'm reading that back trace correctly (Though I have no idea why a chaperone contract is involved, or why it's getting some other value). Changing the rest type to `Immutable-HashTable` doesn't change anything, and the tables returned by TR's `for/hasheqv` are immutable ones.

Any ideas on what's causing this and how to fix it? (Other than building the final table up with `for/fold` or some other alternative approach, which is my plan if I can't resolve this issue with `hash-union`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that polymorphism in the keys of hash tables doesn't work well with the contracts that Typed Racket puts on it when you import it from untyped Racket. The error message:

```
hash/c: contract violation
  expected: chaperone-contract?
  given: k33
```

Mentions `k33` which comes from your `k` in `(All (k v) .... (Immutable-HashTable k v) ....)`.

The first step to fixing this error is to use a concrete type like `Any` instead of a polymorphic `k`, as in `(All (v) .... (Immutable-HashTable Any v) ....)`.

The next error after that might be something like:

```
hash-union: contract violation
  expected: "hash-equal? (because the key contract is not a flat contract)"
  given: '#hasheqv()
```

This is because `hasheq` and `hasheqv` don't work well with the contracts that Typed Racket puts on it. You can fix that by using `hash` or `hashalw` instead, as in `(for/hash : (Immutable-HashTable Any Integer) ....)`.

If you run into other contract problems that you can't fix in similar ways, it's also possible to bypass the contracts that Typed Racket puts on it, by importing it *unsafely*, but that should be a last-resort.

Comment: I'll have to play around with that tonight. Not a big fan of losing the type safety by using Any though.

Comment: Well if you're only using `hash-union` for this one purpose you can import it with `Char` in that position instead... but then it's not really the general `hash-union` anymore

Comment: Ideally I'd like a general `require/typed` I can just copy into other files without having to tweak it, yeah.

Comment: It looks like I can cast a `(HashTable Any Integer)` to `(HashTable Char Integer)`. A bit ugly to do, but keeps the type safety of a uniform key type downstream.

Comment: Yes, casting works in this case with `Char` because `Char` is a "flat" type which can be checked with a flat contract. With other types, like higher-order ones or mutable ones, those might not work as well in the "key" position of hash tables, so be aware of that